# INSERT *, with extra columns in MERGE Statement

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have 2 tables source and target
Target table has schema like this:
[image: Target table schema]

Source table has schema:

[image]

Now I'm trying to use `merge into` target table as

```
merge into target_table as tgt
  using
  (
    select 
      src.id as mergekey,
      src.*
      from source_table src
  union all
    select
    null as mergekey,
    src.*
    from source_table src
    join target_table tgt
      on tgt.id = src.id
      and tgt.is_current = 1
    where not( tgt.name = src.name )
  ) us
on tgt.id = us.mergekey
when matched
  and tgt.is_current = 1
  and
    not ( tgt.name = src.name )
  then update set
    is_current = 0,
    end_date = '2020-01-08'
when not matched then
insert *, 1 as is_current , '2020-01-09' as start_date, null as end_date
```

The problem occurs on the last line. I'm getting error on last line:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input ',' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 30, pos 8)
```

It works fine if I try to use it in `select *, 1 as is_current , '2020-01-09' as start_date, null as end_date from source_table` but in merge I think the syntax is different but I can't seem to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

After trying different methods, got it working now.

```
insert (key, id, name, is_current, start_date, end_date) 
values(us.key, us.id, us.name , 1, current_date, null)
```

Replacing this line at end. Everything works now.